# encrypt html files using java swing

Tags: java, swing, encryption, jar, setup-project

I am working on a Swing application in which i have to give the HTML files to client but I dont want the client to get access to them.

Is there any way that I can put my  files either in password protected folder or I could encrypt the file and my  program should access them back in the Swing application.

Comment: *"I dont want the client to get access to them."*  So don't put them in the Jar.  Otherwise, the client can get them, even if they are encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encrypt them with a shared hidden key.
One for your application, hardcoded in the software, one for yourself, to encrypt the html files with.

That's about all you can do about it. Once decrypted it is fairly easy to get the contents from it because they can always write their own class which implements your class that simply shows the content(it's about 15 lines of code really, java decompilers work pretty good these days)

Answer (score 2):

Hehe, well that's of course technically possible, but at some point the cleartext will be available to your client - if not by other means, then at least by network sniffing...

Use your resources to write good code and don't bother encrypting your HTML.

Cheers,